# Converting code from C to Java: shifts

Tags: java, c, bit-manipulation

I have some C code, where an unsigned integer is shifted by a (signed) variable. For example,

```
1u << i;
```

When converting to Java, can I just replace it with a signed int?

I think it would be safe for left shifts, but I am not sure about right shifts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, there are two types of right shifts. `>>>` will attach 0's to fill the empty spaces for both positive and negative numbers (logical shift right) while `>>` will attach 1's if negative and 0's if positive (sign extension).

In C and C++, `>>` will insert zeros if the number is positive. However, with negative numbers, this case is implementation dependent. Either zeros or ones might be attached.

[JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) behaves the same way as Java for `>>` and `>>>`.

In C#, when using `>>` for negative numbers, all the exposed bits except for the first are set to 0. The first stays at 1.

Note that for all the above languages, `>>` with positive numbers attaches zeros. Only the case with negative numbers varies. Also, `<<` attaches zeros to the exposed bits for all languages.

Comment: To clarify, `>>` will sign-extend.  So it will attach 1s if the operand is negative.

Comment: @Oli yeah, i was just about to add that myself. thanks though.

Comment: It means >>>.  >> means something else in Java.

Comment: @Ojala in C, >> causes 0's to be filled in when the number is positive. however, when negative numbers are used, either 0's or 1's can be filled in- this is dependent on the implementation. hence, gravitybringer's answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine for left shifts, for right-shifts use the `>>>` operator.

Comment: You could add that `>>>` is the unsigned right shift operator and maybe eloborate why it works rather than the right shift operator `>>`.